# PreferenceActivity - EditTextPreference - on value changed

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, edittextpreference

I have an `EditTextPreference` (key "userfirstname"). I want to call method when it  has been changed. I read documentation of [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) and [EditTextPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html), but I didn't find relevant solution.

Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Preference userNamePref = findPreference("userfirstname");
userNamePref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                Object newValue) {
            //do something
            return true;
        }

});
```